# Repartitioning of large dataset in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 20TB file and I want to repartition it in spark with each partition = 128MB.
But after calculating n=20TB/128mb= 156250 partitions.

I believe 156250 is a very big number for
**df.repartition(156250)**

how should I approach repartitiong in this?

or should I increase the block size from 128mb to let's say **128gb.**
but 128 gb per task will explode executor.

Please help me with this.

Comment: why do you think that value is very big for repartition? the max value for Int is 2147483647

Comment: @Shankar ok , but my context was for spark not the size of int.
I wanted to know in this scenario what should be the partition size for optimal performance, 128mb/ 256mb/ 512mb/ or even 128 gb

Comment: I think a fair size will be 10GB(10240MB) per partition. You are 2048 partitions - which is somewhat fair. If you see this is working, you can go for 5GB partition. Also, i would recommend to use parquet or Avro file type to store this kind of huge table.

Comment: @Jennifer9198 i have worked on multi terrabytes of data, for me 128 MB worked fine. in general 128 MB will work for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer it. You don’t need to load all the dataset in one place cause it would cost you huge amount resources and also network pressure because of shuffle exchanging.

Comment: Assuming the file is in HDFS, it is already divided.

Answer (score 0):

The block size that you are referring to here is an HDFS concept related to storing the data by breaking it into chunks (say 128M default) & replicating thereafter for fault tolerance. In case you are storing your 20TB file on HDFS, it will automatically be broken into `20TB/128mb=156250` chunks for storage.

Coming to the Spark dataframe `repartition`, firstly it is a tranformation rather than an action (more information on the differences between the two: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations). Which means merely calling this function on the dataframe does nothing unless the dataframe is eventually used in some action.

Further, the repartition value allows you to define the parallelism level of your operation involving the dataframe & should mostly be thought upon in those terms rather than the amount of data being processed per executor. The aim should be to maximize parallelism as per the available resources rather than trying to process certain amount of data per executor. The only exception to this rule should be in cases where the executor either needs to persist all this data in memory or collect some information from this data which is proportional to the data size being processed. And the same applies to any executor task running on 128GB of data.